# lxml with schema 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd, lxml

I'm trying to use lxml with the xs:assert validation tag. I've tried using the example from this IBM page:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/

```
<xs:element name="dimension">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:assert test="@height < @width"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

It seems like lxml doesn't support XML Schema 1.1.

Can someone validate this?
What XML (for Python) engine does support Schema 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two schema processors that currently support XSD 1.1 are Xerces and Saxon - both Java based.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the Microsoft technologies?

Comment: Nevermind - The Wikipedia article is pretty informative about this. Thanks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)#Version_1.1

Comment: This answer did not age well. Meanwhile there is as well the python package `xmlschema`.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73685488/1599887).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did write "currently", so I think it aged perfectly well! But I'm very pleased to see that there's a new XSD 1.1 processor now available. The answer also failed to mention the Altova schema processor.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, libxml does not support xsd 1.1. Use [xmlschema](https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/) >=1.0.14 instead.