# Is it possible to validate an XML file against XSD 1.1 in Python?

Tags: python, xsd, schema, lxml

I want validate an XML file against an XSD file using lxml.XMLSchema. But the problem is the XSD is in 1.1. So it doesn't work.

This is a part of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="!!assert.xsd">
  <SizeType>10</SizeType>
</dictionary>
```

And this is its XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="SizeType">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:assertion test="$value = 10"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So, is it possible to validate an XML file against a XSD file that uses `xs:assertion` statements (1.1)?

I think this question is closely related to this: [lxml with schema 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559263/lxml-with-schema-1-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 2022 update

Yes, starting in 2019 it finally became possible to validate XML against XSD 1.1 in Python.

[Davide Brunato](https://github.com/brunato) added [XSD 1.1 support](https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema/issues/75#issuecomment-525241593) to [xmlschema](https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema) (v1.0.14).

<sub><sup>Thanks to [@Alex](https://%3Csup%3E) for pointing out the update.</sup></sub>

### 2013 original answer

As of early November 2013, only the following XML processors support XSD 1.1:

- [Xerces-J with PsychoPath XPath 2.0](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-2)
- [Saxon EE](http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html)
- [Altova](http://www.altova.com/whatsnew_missionkit.html)

There is no XML parser written in Python that validates against XSD 1.1 yet.

Answer (score 3):

xmlschema (1.0.14+) supports XSD 1.1

https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema