# XSD: Restrict only one child element to have specific value

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a XML which reads

```
<Options>
  <option1>Y</option1>
  <option2>N</option2>
  <option3>N</option3>
</Options>
```

I would like to ensure only one child element (of Options) has value Y so that above XML is valid but not the below one.

```
<Options>
  <option1>Y</option1>
  <option2>Y</option2>
  <option3>N</option3>
</Options>
```

I tried unique and referential integrity but couldn't work out.

Any help/idea much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to enforce such a constraint outside of XSD 1.0, but you could use `xs:assert` to enforce it with **XSD 1.1**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="Options">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="option1"/>
        <xs:element name="option2"/>
        <xs:element name="option3"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(* = 'Y') = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

**Or, to avoid separately naming each `option`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="Options">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="option" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(option = 'Y') = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Constraining options to be only `Y` or `N` could of course also been done if desired.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway without assert? Also, is XSD 1.1 is supported by major processor? I tried using assert in Visual Studio 2013, but it didn't work. Any free tools where I can verify XML against XSD 1.1 schema?

Comment: As I mentioned, you'll need XSD 1.1 if you want to do it within XSD.  For a list of processors that support XSD 1.1, see [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19818871/290085).  Thanks.