# Validate XML against XSD 1.1 schema indirectly from Python?

Tags: python, saxon, xsd-validation, xerces, xsd-1.1

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809141/is-it-possible-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-xsd-1-1-in-python) it appears that Python (which version?) is not yet able to implement XSD 1.1 directly.

Would it be possible to somehow call a specific action by another validation framework (e.g. Saxon; Xerces) from a Python script to e.g. validate an XML instance against an XSD 1.1 schema?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to wrap around Saxon/C the C++ version with Python.
You can download it from here:

http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml

It is also worth looking at this third party project called pysaxon, which does exactly what you want: https://github.com/ajelenak/pysaxon

The pysaxon project is designed for the HE edition, but you should be able to make it work with the PE or EE versions.

Comment: Just to add, in case you're not aware, schema validation requires the EE edition of Saxon which needs a paid license.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [xmlschema](https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema) Python xsd schema validator for 1.1.
It is a pure Python solution without a Saxon library dependency.